# SmugMug: Is there an issue here?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I'm slightly concerned about the [SmugMug proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25069/smugmug). It seems likely to me, given the speed at which this was set up, the number of followers who admit working for the company, and the number of followers who follow that proposal and nothing else, that this was set up by the company themselves. I guess my question is: is this a problem?

Comment: Wow; the commit comments read like a set of customer testimonials

Comment: Additionally, you'll note that the CEO referred a large number of people (148).  Also, most of the commitments happened on one day (December 3rd).  At a guess, there was an appeal on message boards and/or blogs.

Comment: Yep, it was set up by the company (aka me).  The guys running StackOverflow recommended we go this route to get things rolling, so that's what we're doing.  You can see my blog post on it here:  http://don.blogs.smugmug.com/2010/12/15/my-love-affair-with-stackexchange-and-a-plea-for-help/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While they have enough followers to meet the "move to commitment" criteria and these followers have cast enough votes, they'll either need to attract users from existing sites or participate in other sites themselves in order for the proposal to progress.

The commitment percentage is based on the reputation of those committing (with a factor based on how many sites you're active on). If they don't have any reputation elsewhere in the system the commitment percentage won't grow.

If they can get enough commitment from other users then I don't see why the site shouldn't be allowed to progress - it will have to get through beta as well don't forget.